# Is there a MAPI API for .NET Applications?

Tags: .net, email, mapi, exchange-server

Data comes in by email as a zipped file. The Java solution we wrote tried to parse and download the email automatically and load the data. We ran into all kinds of problems getting through the firewall, and eventually the solution just got put on hold. Because the administrators wouldn’t allow access to an anonymous type of email box.

The account is currently pop3 – they want to move the email server and change the account type to native MAPI. This would not work with a java solution as no java -> MAPI API exists.

Would a .net solution would work? Is there a MAPA API for .NET applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly you cannot use MAPI directly from .NET (well you can but MS don't support it). See http://blogs.msdn.com/stephen_griffin/archive/2009/04/03/mapi-and-net.aspx

However there is a COM component called Redemption (google for Outlook Remption - can't post more than  hyperlink yet! ) available which you can use .NET interop with as an out-of-process COM server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can access mapi through COM InterOP.
It is considered to be slow and less effectice.
check Visual studio tools for office for a better approach.